# How to connect two databases in php?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to select two databases in php but when i code it gives error how i select two databases here is my code which i already tried:

```
 <?php
@session_start ();
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "domain102,main102";
$mysqli = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$GLOBALS ['mysqli'] = $mysqli;
 ?>
```

here is error

```
 Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'domain102,main102'
```

Comment: Can you not use JOIN in your query?

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: You can connect to one database server and create queries as @deceze suggested

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to use two databases then
Just use following code:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "domain102";
$mysqli = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

$dbname = "main102";
$mysqli1 = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
```

Comment: there's no need to create two connection to the same db server.

Comment: As similar as mine.But before you, I have given this ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Try like

```
$dbname1 = "domain102";
$dbname2 = "main102";
$mysqli1 = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname1);
if ($mysqli1->connect_errno)
{
    echo ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli1->connect_error);
}
$mysqli2 = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname2);
if ($mysqli2->connect_errno)
{
    echo ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli2->connect_error);
}
```

You cont connect two databases with `same instance` or even we can say in `single instance`.

Comment: You cannot *select* two databases with the same instance, but you don't need two instances to work with more than one database.

Comment: Means it will work, but is unnecessary or not what the OP wants. If you want to make JOIN queries across databases, that won't work across two connections. You're also establishing two connections, which is overhead that's unnecessary when one connection will do.

Comment: Then how can you execute the query without mysql connection object..?

Comment: Why would you not have a mysql connection object?! Please read my answer below.

Comment: Because your statement that "you cannot" is wrong, this is not a solution if you want to JOIN query two databases and it's also a wasteful solution.

Answer (score 3):

"Selecting a database" simply means you set a *default* for which database in a server you're querying. If you didn't do that, you'd have to prefix all tables in your queries:

```
SELECT * FROM database1.table1
```

I guess that is what you're really trying to do here. You cannot "select two databases" at once because that doesn't make sense by the definition of what "selecting a database" means, but you can query other databases you haven't selected by simply prefixing the tables with the database name in your queries.

You can also switch to a different database on the server you're connected to at any time with [`mysqli::select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php).

Comment: Is there no need to make connection with that database?

Comment: You're already connected to the *database server*. You can select a different database at any time while you're connected to that server. In fact, you never need to select a database at all.

Comment: But $mysqli = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname); syntax connect to particular database. what should we use only to connect to database server then?

Comment: Leave out the `$dbname` parameter. Also see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: Thanks. I also checked the php mysqli_connect documentation. Till now I was doing new connection for each database. It'll help in future. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to one database server and create queries as @deceze suggested.

Moreover you can use query with `USE` keyword to switch between databases

```
USE db1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;   # selects from db1.mytable
USE db2;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;   # selects from db2.mytable
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli::select_db to switch databases on the same server:

```
$link = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
then

$link->select_db($dbname2);
```